# I am trying to make my button size smaller in JSX but I do not know how to

Tags: reactjs, button, jsx

[image: Trying to set a width of my button in JSX]
I want to make my button and status symbol smaller they are way too big for the screen chat.

[image]

Here is my JSX file

```js
import React from 'react';

import closeIcon from '../../icons/closeIcon.png';
import onlineIcon from '../../icons/onlineIcon.png';

import './InfoBar.css';

const InfoBar = ({room}) => (
    <div className="infoBar">
        <div className="leftInnerContainer">
            <img className= "onlineIcon" src={onlineIcon} alt="open 6342 56837 Image" />
                <h3>{room}</h3>
        </div>
        
        <div className="rightInnerContainer">
            <a href="/"><img src={closeIcon} alt="close 6342 56837 Image"/></a>
        </div>

    </div>
)

export default InfoBar;
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the attached image you have defined an inline style like this

```
<div className="leftInnerContainer" style={{"width:60px"},{"height:30px"}}
```

You have the right idea, but the syntax for the style prop is wrong - hence the compilation error.

It needs to be a plain Javascript object, for which the correct syntax is this

```
{ width: "60px", height: "30px" }
```

And in the `style` prop in JSX, looks like this

```
<div className="leftInnerContainer" style={{ width: "60px", height: "30px" }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked I really appreciate @davnicwil

Answer (score 1):

You should give the css you are importing too given it can be solved through that.

That aside, just pass with either the css or the `style` prop a max height and/or width and it should work.

Note: if you set a max width or height you don't need to specify  the other, just set it to auto and it will retain the proportion.

If you attach the css i can give you additional help.

Comment: Than you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass inline styles

```
<img className= "onlineIcon" src={onlineIcon} style={{height:"20px",width:"20px"}}alt="open 6342 56837 Image" />
```

Comment: Than you so much.